# How to define an isotopy from the lower hemisphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a closed disk in the $xy$-plane?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

Define an isotopy from the lower hemisphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a closed disk in the $xy$-plane

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Let $L \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the lower hemisphere, i.e.
\begin{align*}
L=\{(x,y,z) : x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z \leq 0\}
\end{align*}
Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the closed disk in the $xy$-plane, i.e.
\begin{align*}
D=\{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}
\end{align*}

a. Give an explicit isotopy $h: L \times I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ from $L$ to $D$.

Let $h: L\times I\to \R^3$ be given by,
\begin{align*}
h((x,y,z),t)=(x,y,(1-t)z)
\end{align*}
b. Give an explicit isotopy from $D$ to $L$.

Let $g: D\times I\to \R^3$ be given by
\begin{align*}
g((x,y,z),t)=(x,y,-t\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})
\end{align*}

For both (a) and (b) I verified that when $t=0$, $h(x,t)=L$ and $g(x,t)=D$, and also when $t=1$ then $h(x,t)=D$ and $g(x,t)=L$ so I believe they should be isotopies, but is this correct?

Comment: For $g$, you probably mean $(x,y, -t \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$ instead. Also what's your definition of isotopy? Depending on that you probably want to do some extra checks as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. The idea is to *move points vertically*.

For $g$ I would recommend to write

$$g((x,y,0),t ) = (x,y,-t\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$$
because the variable $z$ in your formula may be confusing. And you should not write $h(x,t)=L$ etc. Instead write $h(L \times \{1\}) = D$ etc. This means that

1. $h(\xi,1) \in D$ for all $\xi = (x,y,z) \in L$ (which is obvious since $h(\xi,1) = (x,y,0)$ and $x^2 + y^2 \le x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$).
2. Each $\eta = (x,y,0) \in L$ has the form $\eta = h(\xi,1)$ for some $\xi \in L$. In fact,take $\xi = (x,y,-\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$.

It remains to show each $h_t : L \to \mathbb R^3, h_t(\xi) = h(\xi,t)$, is a homeomorphism onto its image. Since $L$ is compact and $h_t(L)$ is Hausdorff, it suffices to show that $h_t$ is injective. But this is trivial because all points in $L$ are uniquely determined by their first two coordinates $(x,y)$.

Comment: Excellent additions to my understanding of the problem. What is this symbol: ξ?

Comment: It is the Greek letter "xi". I only used it as an abbreviation of a real triple.